# Avoiding calling "point" every time I need empty Writer

Tags: scalaz

```scala
type EventWriter[A] = Writer[List[Event], A]
type EitherWriter[A] = EitherT[EventWriter, String, A]

def applyChange(event: Event): EitherWriter[Aggregate] =
  EitherT.right[EventWriter, String, Aggregate](handleEvent(event).set(event :: Nil))
```

and this is used like:

```scala
def close = {
  if (!closed) {
    applyChange(Closed(id))
  } else {
    this.point[EitherWriter]
  }
}
```

Can I avoid explicitly returning `this.point[EitherWriter]` every time I want to return `this` with empty list?